# Remove button from plugin

Tags: css, button, plugins

I am trying to figure out how to remove some buttons from a plugin. I don't want to change the plugins code, since i won't be able to get updates any more. The thing is I can't either use css rules display:none, because I want 2 buttons in the list to remain, and all of them have the same class name.

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="cdm_nav_buttons" id="cdm_nav_buttons">
    <a href="#upload" class="sp_cdm_add_file hide_add_file_permission">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add File
    </a>
    <a href="#add-link" class="sp_cdm_add_file hide_add_file_permission" style="
        ">Add Link</a>
    <a href="#add-embed" class="sp_cdm_add_file hide_add_file_permission">Embed Video</a>
    <a href="#folder" class="sp_cdm_add_folder hide_add_folder_permission">
        <i class="fa fa-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Folder
    </a>
    <a href="javascript:cdm_ajax_search()" class="sp_cdm_refresh">
        <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i> Refresh
    </a>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

I want only two buttons to remain. How can I do this without editing the source code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with CSS either by the `:nth-*` pseudo-classes (check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)) or by attribute selectors (check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)). Both are quite flexible and you should be able to do the trick with these.

Example:

```
div.cdm_nav_buttons a:nth-child(2), div.cdm_nav_buttons a:nth-child(3) {
    display:none;
}
```

or

```
a[href="#upload"], a[href="#folder"] {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very useful!! In the end I found a feature that allowed this functionality to be placed. No need to use these lines, but very helpful indeed!

Answer (score 0):

you could use the `:nth-child()` selector:
for example:

```
.cdm_nav_buttons a:nth-child(2){
  display:none;
}
```

This only "removes" the second `<a>` inside the `cdm_nav_buttons` div.

instead of `a` you could also use its class:

```
.cdm_nav_buttons .sp_cdm_add_file:nth-child(2){
      display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
.cdm_nav_buttons a:nth-child(5){
  display: none;
}

.cdm_nav_buttons a:nth-child(2){
  display: none;
}
```

More info can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp